# Listview builder not taking full List Map data Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have set of List> data which contains the values name, amount and date of products. I am passing the data into a listview builder to render as a list of cards for each product.

The product list passed:

> [{name: Product 1, amount: 24.5, date: 2019-07-14 00:00:00.000}, {name:
>   Product 2, amount: 29.5, date: 2019-07-14 00:00:00.000}, {name: Product 3,
>   amount: 29.5, date: 2019-07-15 00:00:00.000}]

The listview works fine, However I am trying to add a function where the listview filters the products by the date created. For this I'm passing a date through the datetime picker (using setState and the default value is **DateTime.now()**) and comparing the products date with selected date from the datetime picker.

Please find the code below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:learning_app/product.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class BuildProduct extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> products;
  final Function updateProduct;
  final DateTime selectedDate;

  Tasks(this.products, this.updateProduct, this.selectedDate);

  Widget _buildCard() {
    DateTime _currentDate = DateTime.now();

    Widget ProductCard = Center(
      child: Text('No Products added'),
    );
    if (products.length > 0) {
      ProductCard = ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: products.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          print("Product List: " + products.toString());
          print("Product Name: " + products[index]['name'].toString());
          print("Product Date: " + products[index]['date'].toString());
          print("Selected Date: " + selectedDate.toString());
          if(DateFormat.yMMMd().format(products[index]['date']) ==
                DateFormat.yMMMd().format(selectedDate)) {
            return ProductCard(products[index], index, updateProduct);
          }
        }
      );
    }
    return ProductCard;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildCard();
  }
}
```

The problem with the code is that if I select a different date to a new product (i.e the third product), the listview builder does not take it in the loop, even worse when i pass a new date as the number of products in the loop decreases by 1. Please find the print statements below for reference(The one in the codes)

When the page is opened with the default date:

```
I/flutter (11152): Product List: [{name: Product 1, amount: 24.5, date: 2019-07-14 00:00:00.000}, {name: Product 2, amount: 29.5, date: 2019-07-14 00:00:00.000}, {name: Product 3, amount: 29.5, date: 2019-07-15 00:00:00.000}]
I/flutter (11152): Product Name: Product 1
I/flutter (11152): Product Date: 2019-07-14 20:13:05.838550
I/flutter (11152): Selected Date: 2019-07-14 20:15:32.687104
I/flutter (11152): Product List: //same list as above
I/flutter (11152): Product Name: Product 2
I/flutter (11152): Product Date: 2019-07-14 20:13:32.398186
I/flutter (11152): Selected Date: 2019-07-14 20:15:32.687104
I/flutter (11152): Product List: //same list as above
I/flutter (11152): Product Name: Product 3
I/flutter (11152): Product Date: 2019-07-15 00:00:00.000
I/flutter (11152): Selected Date: 2019-07-14 20:15:32.687104
```

and when i select another date (i.e 2019-07-15) :

```
I/flutter (11152): Product List: [{name: Product 1, amount: 24.5, date: 2019-07-14 00:00:00.000}, {name: Product 2, amount: 29.5, date: 2019-07-14 00:00:00.000}, {name: Product 3, amount: 29.5, date: 2019-07-15 00:00:00.000}]
I/flutter (11152): Product Name: Product 1
I/flutter (11152): Product Date: 2019-07-14 20:13:05.838550
I/flutter (11152): Selected Date: 2019-07-15 12:00:00.000Z
I/flutter (11152): Product List: //same list as above
I/flutter (11152): Product Name: Product 2
I/flutter (11152): Product Date: 2019-07-14 20:13:32.398186
I/flutter (11152): Selected Date: 2019-07-15 12:00:00.000Z7104
```

I want to render only the products(cards) with the same date as the selected date when the date is selected. Please help me find the error in my implementation or suggest a better method for achieving the goal. Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: why not just compare the `DateTime` objects? Why are you formatting it to String?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think this will help you rather than converting it to strings and then comparing use the `difference()` method available in `DateTime` class. You can also use `inDays` property just to get the difference in days

code:

```
if(products[index]['date'].difference(selectedDate).inDays == 0) {
  return ProductCard(products[index], index, updateProduct);
}
```

Comment: I used the date time format to obtain only the date as the difference() method compares both the date and time instead of the date only.

Comment: Thanks for the better code recommendation, however the problem I encountered still exists (where the listview builder does not accept all products to the loop)